# Is it possible to remove wrapper element in WS result?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf

I have CXF project working fine.

My WS interface is

```java
package net.betlista.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.apache.cxf.annotations.EndpointProperty;

@WebService
public interface TestWs {

    @WebMethod
    Result foo(String child);

}
```

implementation is

```java
package net.betlista.ws;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("testWsEndpoint")
public class TestWsImpl implements TestWs {

    @Override
    public Result foo(final String child) {
        Result res = new Result();
        res.status = "ok";
        res.data = "bar";
        return res;
    }

}
```

Result type class:

```java
package net.betlista.ws;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

//@XmlTransient - NOT working
@XmlType
//@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE) - NOT working
public class Result {

    @XmlElement
    String status;

    @XmlElement
    String data;

}
```

When I call the WS with request:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.betlista.net/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:foo>
         <arg0>a</arg0>
      </ws:foo>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

the result is:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:fooResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.betlista.net/">
         <return>
            <status>ok</status>
            <data>bar</data>
         </return>
      </ns2:fooResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And I'd like to skip this `return` element.

I'd like to have:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:fooResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.betlista.net/">
        <status>ok</status>
        <data>bar</data>
      </ns2:fooResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270079/jax-ws-change-location-of-xmlns-attribute/14272640#14272640) question, but if I use this, element `arg` is also missing from request what is something I do not want.

I tried to use this `@SOAPBinding` annotation for method (works as described  above) and also for type `Result` (not working).

Requested WSDL:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.betlista.net/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="TestWsImplService" targetNamespace="http://ws.betlista.net/">
  <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://ws.betlista.net/" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.betlista.net/" version="1.0">
<xs:element name="foo" type="tns:foo"/>
<xs:element name="fooResponse" type="tns:fooResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="foo">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="fooResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:result"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="result">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="status" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="data" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="foo">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:foo" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="fooResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:fooResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="TestWs">
    <wsdl:operation name="foo">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:foo" name="foo">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:fooResponse" name="fooResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="TestWsImplServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:TestWs">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="foo">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="foo">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="fooResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="TestWsImplService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:TestWsImplServiceSoapBinding" name="TestWsImplPort">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/tests-wicket-cxf/ws/TestWs"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Can you put in the wsdl?

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan: I think WSDL is irrelevant, but I added it. WSDL is generated from classes above...

Comment: @BetLista, WSDL decides the soap request structure and response structure. This is the default structure of wsdl generated by cxf's java2wsdl. You can customize it as per your needs as well.

Comment: @BetLista, as per your webservice, it is suppose to return an object of Result class and Result is a non-standard class w.r.t xsd. So, if you observe the wsdl, it says, fooResponse may have an element of any type (xsd:anyType) and just sends the fields of the Result class as the response. What problem do you have with return statement?

Comment: Sorry, `xsd:anyType` was there because I was trying something (it was not working). I know I can rename the element... I added example what I'd like to achieve... Result tag is there because of technical reasons - java method has at most one return type... `return` element is (from business point of view) meaningless...

Comment: in previous comment "Result tag is there ..." had to be "return tag is there ..."

Answer (score 6):

If you want to replace arg0 with child within the SOAP request, you should add a `@WebParam(name="child")` annotation to your method parameter.

You can furthermore take influence on the produced style by annotating the service (the class) with `@SOAPBinding(...)` - which style to use depends on your needs/whises - here please refer to the link of my first comment to see the differences.

Further, please have a look at the [CXF docs](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-service.html) to see the default values for each `@SOAPBinding` parameter.

As you want to get rid of the `return` element in the response, please note that this is not WS-I complient, as only one soap::body child is allowed - but as this is your intention you should change the `ParameterStyle.WRAPPED` default SOAPBinding parameter to `ParameterStyle.BARE`. This however might change the request type too. Maybe have a look at `@ResponseWrapper` here. I haven't used it yet so I can't give detailed information therefore.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about "this is not WS-I complient" part? Because I do not see the reason why I cannot replace reference to result `<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:anyType"/>` with it's definition... Please be aware that I changed the WSDL, previous was wrong.

Comment: I read your answer again, and soap:body has exactly one element - `fooResponse`... I want to get rid of `return` element...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `<return>`tag you can use your own tag like `<result>` by adding @javax.jws.WebResult(name = "result") both in your interface and implementation.

```
@Override
@javax.jws.WebResult(name = "result")
public Result foo(final String child) {
    Result res = new Result();
    res.status = "ok";
    res.data = "bar";
    return res;
}
```